# Drupal populate date field using ajax

Tags: ajax, date, drupal, callback, populate

Need help to populate Drupal form API DATE Field in ajax call back , i tried most of the things but nothing works , normal textfields and all populating but date field alone not working

Comment: Which Drupal version do you use? Are you using Drupal's AJAX commands to alter the field values, or are you returning new form items to replace the old ones (with new values)?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which version you're using, but on Drupal 7, it looks like the trick is to add an extra 'date'/'time'/ hierarchical array, like that:

```
// Element declaration.
$form['date_to'] = array(
  '#title' => t('Date to.'),
  '#type' => 'date_popup'
  '#size' => 20,
  '#default_value' => date('Y-m-d H:i'),
  '#date_format' => 'Y-m-d H:i',
  '#required' => FALSE,
);

// In Ajax callback.
$form['date_to']['#value']['date'] = $date_to;
$form['date_to']['#value']['time'] = $time_to;
```